# What is the difference between formal & standard written English?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *formal written English* and *standard written English*? Can standard written English be formal or vice versa? Are these synonymous or is there a distinctive difference (albeit, a small one)?

I always assumed the presence of contractions in a piece would make it *standard written English*, but if it were to be *formal*, then it needed to be without contractions. I do not know where I came up with this idea or if it is even substantial.

I would appreciate if someone explained this to me.

Comment: You seem to be talking about *speech*, but when you say "contractions in a piece", that indicates writing. Are you distinguishing between written and spoken English?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous writing, yes, I meant written English in all cases. It was my mistake to refer to spoken English.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you don't mind, I'll edit the question to reflect it.

Comment: There is no standard for "formal" (or for "standard" for that matter).  Formal language used in a job resume would be vastly different from formal language used when inviting the President to some event.  And that would be different from inviting the Queen.

Comment: The difference is no doubt...the formalness - or perhaps the standardness. But @HotLicks nailed it: define "*formal English*" and "*standard English*", please.

Comment: The comment by Hot Licks is spot on. This question is entirely unanswerable until you define what you mean by the two terms you only just invented, or randomly came across being invented by someone else. These are no established terms with a commonly accepted meaning. *Standard English*, with a capital *S*, is an established term. And so is *written Standard English*. But *standard written English* is not. Much less *formal written English*. That is not a term. Just two adjectives tacked onto a noun. So we can tell you absolutely nothing about it. We don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Formal speech is a concrete concept. Minimal contractions, few idioms, no cuss words, no slang, flawless phraseology. The meaning of "standard" falls just short of "anything at all" and depends heavily on the context.

Comment: "speech"?  Isn't the question about "written English"?